# Perl: Connect to remote database SSL error

Tags: mysql, perl, ssl

I'm trying to run a Perl script that connects to a remote MySQL database. I have MySQL installed locally on OSX via Homebrew.

This is the error:

```
DBI connect('database connection details') failed: SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)
```

How can I resolve this error, or get Perl to ignore SSL?

I've tried adding mysql_ssl=0, but the error still occurs.

Code:

```
# PERL MYSQL CONNECT()
$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$db;host=$host", $user, $password, {RaiseError => 1});
$dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'} = 1;
$dbh->{'mysql_ssl'} = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mysql_ssl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql#mysql_ssl) is not a handle attribute. If you try to use it like one, it's ignored, which you can see by turning on tracing:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

DBI->trace('1|CON');

my $dsn = 'DBI:mysql:test';
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, 'foo', '', {
    PrintError => 0,
    RaiseError => 1,
    mysql_ssl  => 0  # equivalent to $dbh->{mysql_ssl} = 0
});
```

Output:

```
    DBI 1.627-ithread default trace level set to 0x200/1 (pid 30834 pi 1d0e010) at db line 8
    -> DBI->connect(DBI:mysql:test, foo, ****, HASH(0x1d3b550))
    -> DBI->install_driver(mysql) for linux perl=5.016003 pid=30834 ruid=12011 euid=12011
       install_driver: DBD::mysql version 4.023 loaded from /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/DBD/mysql.pm
    <- install_driver= DBI::dr=HASH(0x1e33a10)
    !! warn: 0 CLEARED by call to connect method
    -> connect for DBD::mysql::dr (DBI::dr=HASH(0x1e33a10)~0x1e33bf0 'test' 'foo' **** HASH(0x1e4d808)) thr#1d0e010
    <- connect= ( DBI::db=HASH(0x1f65fe0) ) [1 items] at DBI.pm line 670
    <- STORE('RaiseError', 1)= ( 1 ) [1 items] at DBI.pm line 722
    <- STORE('PrintError', 0)= ( 1 ) [1 items] at DBI.pm line 722
    <- STORE('AutoCommit', 1)= ( 1 ) [1 items] at DBI.pm line 722
    <- STORE('Username', 'foo')= ( 1 ) [1 items] at DBI.pm line 725
$h->{'mysql_ssl'}=0 ignored for invalid driver-specific attribute
```

Instead, add it to the DSN:

```
my $dsn = 'DBI:mysql:test;mysql_ssl=0';
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, 'foo', '', {
    PrintError => 0,
    RaiseError => 1
});
```

Depending on the server configuration, you may still have issues (like if the server is configured to require SSL).